# My c program is skipping the fprinf and not writing the data in to the designated file especially after the first printf

Tags: c

### Problem

The Program is not writing anything to the file after the first `printf` (please remove `getchar()` to test the program). I don't know what's going on with program: it is running smoothly but it is not writing to the file.

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h> // Header for Windows API that is used by Windows programmers
#include <stdlib.h>
int add_book(){
// begin function
    char choice;
    int book_continue=0;

char book_title[200], book_author[200];
int book_isbn;
int lib_id;
} ;
struct Library profile[60];//Declaration of array of struct.
FILE *libraryrecords;

      system("Color B0");
       libraryrecords = fopen("Library Book Records.txt","w");//file logs has been opened in append mode
      while  (book_continue<30) {
        printf("Enter the Title of a Book\n\n");
        scanf("%s", profile[library_amount].book_title);// reads the variable
        printf("Enter the Book's Author\n\n");
        scanf("%s", profile[library_amount].book_author);
        printf("Enter the Book's ISBN\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &profile[library_amount].book_isbn);
        printf("Enter the state of the Book\n\n");
        scanf(" %c",&state_of_book);//allows the program to recognise a single character with white space behined %c
        printf("Please enter the borrowed date of the book :\n\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &day_borrowed, &month_borrowed, &year_borrowed);//this reads three integer variables
        printf("Please enter the Return Date :\n\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &day_returned, &month_returned, &year_returned);
        printf("Enter his/her library id\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &profile[library_amount].lib_id);
        printf("Type a to Continue or b to Stop \n\n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t Loading");
        system("cls");
        Sleep(600);
        printf("...");

        system("cls"); // Clears the screen
           if(choice== 'b'){
           printf("\n||===================================================================================||\n");
           printf("The book record:\t Book Title: %s, \t Book isbn: %d, \t Author : %s", profile[library_amount].book_title, profile[library_amount].book_isbn, profile[library_amount].book_author);
           printf("\n||===================================================================================||\n");
           Sleep(200);
           getchar()
           fprintf(libraryrecords,"\n||===================================================================================||\n");
           fprintf(libraryrecords,"The book record:\t Book Title: %s, \t Book isbn: %d, \t Author : %s", profile[library_amount].book_title, profile[library_amount].book_isbn, profile[library_amount].book_author);
           fprintf(libraryrecords,"\n||===================================================================================||\n");
            Sleep(100);
              }

                     system("cls");
                      if (day_returned-day_borrowed>10){
                        day_returned=day_late;
                        month_returned=month_late;
                        year_returned=year_late;
                        fprintf(libraryrecords,"\n================================================================\n");
                        fprintf(libraryrecords,"\n\tThe Late Book Return Fee is:\t Fee: %f", late_bookreturn_fee);
                        Sleep(600);
                          fprintf(libraryrecords,"\n==================================================================================\n");
                          fprintf(libraryrecords,"\nPrint The Personal Information of the Person(s) Who is/are Expected to Pay the Fee:\t Name: %s, \t Library id: %d", profile[library_amount].student_mem_name, profile[library_amount].lib_id);
                          Sleep(600);
                          printf("...");
                          system("cls"); // Clears the screen
                          /* This is the nested if else statement due to the amount of expressions where the the { starts after the else if statement*/
                            if (state_of_book== 'a'){//if condition of if 'a' is true
                              fprintf(libraryrecords,"\nThe book is in excellent condition\n\n");//
                              Sleep(600);
                              printf("...");
                              }//end if
                                else if   (state_of_book== 'b'){
                                  fprintf(libraryrecords,"\nThe Book is in Good Condition\n\n");
                                  printf("...");
                                  Sleep(600);
                                  }//end else if

                                    else if   (state_of_book== 'c'){
                                      fprintf(libraryrecords,"\n===============================================\n");
                                      fprintf(libraryrecords,"\nThe Book is in Terrible Condition\n");
                                      book_repayment++;
                                      fprintf(libraryrecords,"\nThe person(s) Who are Required to Repay for a Book are: \n \t Book repayment: %f, \t Library id: %d", book_repayment, profile[library_amount].lib_id);
                                      printf("...");
                                      Sleep(800);
                                      system("cls");
                                      break;
                                      fclose(libraryrecords);
                                 }//end else if
                          }//end if
                      }//end if
                      return 0;
}//end function
```

Comment: Correction It's not writing to the file.

Comment: Start by checking the return value of `fopen`...

Comment: @OP, in the future, please edit your question with crucial details like that. The question should be complete without the use of comments. Comments should be used to respond to tangential issues and discuss things.

Answer (score 0):

Most of that code is not in a function, so it does nothing. `add_book()` ends early.

```
int add_book(){
// begin function
    char choice;
    int book_continue=0;

char book_title[200], book_author[200];
int book_isbn;
int lib_id;
} ;   <<<<<<<<------ add_book() ENDS HERE
struct Library profile[60];//Declaration of array of struct.
FILE *libraryrecords;

      system("Color B0");
       libraryrecords = fopen("Library Book Records.txt","w");//file logs has been opened in append mode
      while  (book_continue<30) {
        printf("Enter the Title of a Book\n\n");
        scanf("%s", profile[library_amount].book_title);// reads the variable
```

You should have gotten a warning indicating a problem like:

```
test.c:12:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
} ;
^
test.c:12:3: warning: extra ';' outside of a function [-Wextra-semi]
} ;
  ^
```

Most compilers do not have warnings on by default. With a command line compiler, you generally turn on most warnings with the `-Wall` flag. Turn them on, fix them all.

This is also a good lesson on proper indentation. With properly indented code, the problem would have been immediately obvious...

```
int add_book(){
    // begin function
    char choice;
    int book_continue=0;

    char book_title[200], book_author[200];
    int book_isbn;
    int lib_id;
} ;
struct Library profile[60];//Declaration of array of struct.
FILE *libraryrecords;

system("Color B0");
libraryrecords = fopen("Library Book Records.txt","w");//file logs has been opened in append mode
while  (book_continue<30) {
    printf("Enter the Title of a Book\n\n");
    scanf("%s", profile[library_amount].book_title);// reads the variable
```

Note how `struct Library profile[60];` and everything following it is indented left from the rest of `add_book`. That visually indicates it's escaped `add_book`'s scope.

Most decent editors have a way to automatically indent code for you. If yours does not, [Atom](https://atom.io/) is a good choice. It's free, integrates well with Git, cross platform, has lots of features and plugins. Auto Indent is in Edit -> Lines -> Auto Indent.

---

Moving on from there, the next problem is you never check if the `fopen` worked. It's important to check that ***every*** system call succeeded. The typical pattern is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // for exit()
#include <string.h>   // for strerror()
#include <errno.h>    // for errno

const char library_file[] = "Library Book Records.txt";
FILE *library_fp = fopen(library_file,"w");
if( library_fp == NULL ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Could not open '%s' for writing: %s", library_file, strerror(errno) );
    exit(1);
}
```

You try the system operation, check if it succeeded. If it didn't, print a useful error message and exit (or do something else to deal with the problem). `errno` is a global variable containing the error from the last system operation, like `fopen`. But it's a number, `strerror(errno)` turns it into a human readable string.